# Bootstrap Active Menu Changes Navbar Height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I added a 2px border-bottom to the active menu(bootstrap). But because of that, my navbar resizes automaticaly. Example: my navbar is 70px height and after adding that 2px border-bottom, my navbar resizes to 72px. I would like to know how to block that. I tried with min/max-height but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="nbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="active-page" href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Host2</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Host3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


.active-page
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F40612;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this?

```
.navbar-right {
   height: 68px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #F40612;
}
```

Or

```
.navbar-right {
   height: 70px;
}

.navbar-nav li {
   background-color: #F40612;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

or jQuery

```
<script>
  $(".active-page").parent().addClass("hightlight");
</script>

.hightlight {
   background-color: #F40612;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. If I put this, the navbar also resizes.

Comment: EDIT: I found the solution in your code. Thank you! .active-page
{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #F40612;
 padding-bottom: 23px !important;
}